# node.js async and await problem with multer

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to take the log in regular sequence

(call1, call2, call3)

but result.. call2, call3, call1...

what can I do??

I used promise.. but result is same..
here is some code

```
{
..
if (typeof files['images1'] !== 'undefined' && files['images1'].length > 0) {
        convertToWebp(files['images1'])
        console.log(2)

    }
if (typeof files['images2'] !== 'undefined' && files['images2'].length > 0) {
        convertToWebp(files['images2'])
        console.log(2)

    }
    console.log(3)

    res.send~
}

async function convertToWebp(files :  MulterFile[]){
    files.forEach(async function(file) {
        await sharp(file.path).webp({quality:70}).toFile("some_rule", async (err, info) => { 
            await deleteFile(file.filename)
            console.log(1)
         }) 
    })
/*
await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    await sharp(file.path).webp({quality:70}).toFile("some_rule",  async (err, info) => { 
        await deleteFile(file.filename)
        console.log(1)
         }) 
      }))
*/
 }

function deleteFile(image : string){
    ..
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the syntax. why are you use callbacks suppose to use await

Comment: when res.send called.. android need to refresh info.. so I need the synchronous processing

Comment: best way don't refresh info in android.. but in my logic that is so difficult.. and I don't have a time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await doesnt work in array iterations function(forEach,map,etc...)

you will have to write normal loop,

```js
(async()=>{
if (typeof files['images1'] !== 'undefined' && files['images1'].length > 0) {
        await convertToWebp(files['images1'])
        console.log(2)

    }
if (typeof files['images2'] !== 'undefined' && files['images2'].length > 0) {
       await convertToWebp(files['images2'])
        console.log(2)

    }
    console.log(3)

    res.send~
}
})()

async function convertToWebp(files :  MulterFile[]){

for(let i in files){
  const file = files[i]
  await sharp(file.path).webp({quality:70}).toFile("some_rule")
  await deleteFile(file.filename)

}
```

Comment: it is the same as my result.. between await sharp and  await deleteFile I inserted call0  but it was called after call3...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async function convertToWebp(files :  MulterFile[]) {
 await Promise.all(files.map(async(file) => {
    const info = await sharp(file.path).webp({quality:70}).toFile("some_rule");
        if(info) {
            const deleteFile = await deleteFile(file.filename)            
            console.log(1) 
       }
 }))
```

}

Comment: it is the same as my result.. between await sharp and  await deleteFile I inserted call0  but it was called after call3...